# 'Get' REST Call in Java: when does it actually execute?

Tags: java, rest, get

For this 'Get' REST call, I wanted to know if I can get the latency of when the HTTP request actually gets executed, nothing else. I am pretty sure I don't start it when I call 'openConnection()' because I don't set the properties for the request method/property till after that, I currently have my startTime right before I set the request method/property but I don't know if my HTTP request executes until I get the results from the input stream. Any clarification I would appreciate.

```
try { 
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/REST/json/product/get");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); 

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));

    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println(duration);

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server ...");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(output);
    } 
    conn.disconnect(); 
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what metric you are interested in? Normally "latency" would imply the time waiting for a response, but your question seemed to imply that you may be interested in the time it takes to put together the request and send it out, or just the time involved in sending the request. As a side note, BufferedReader is probably not a good choice here, as you probably want to take the time the first packet gets back as the end time, rather than the time it takes for BufferedReader to be satisfied with the amount that it has collected.

Comment: What I want is how long does it take for the get request to fully execute, so say I put the query URL browser, I want the time to start when I click 'enter' and stop it when the page returns with the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to put the start time before call to  `connection.getInputStream()`,Only after this line actual connection with server is made.

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));    
endTime = System.nanoTime();
```

The below line does not initiate the connection process,But just set the attributes for the connection(method,data type)

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

For more info :- [HttpURLConnection](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection)